# How can I swap pairs of elements in a stack?

Tags: java, stack

Trying to write a function that takes a stack of integers as a parameter.
By only using one queue as auxiliary storage, I need to swap positions of each pair of elements.

If the stack is odd numbered, leave the final integer where it is.

**INPUT**

```
[3, 8, 17, 9, 99, 9, 17, 8, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14]
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
[8, 3, 9, 17, 9, 99, 8, 17, 1, 3, 3, 2, 14, 4]
```

**CURRENT RESULT**

```
[3, 8, 17, 9, 99, 9, 17, 8, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14, 8, 3, 9, 17, 9, 99, 8, 17, 1, 3]
```

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();   
    int size = st. size();
    for(int i = 0; i < st.size()-1; i++){        
        q.add(st.elementAt(i+1));
        q.add(st.elementAt(i++));
     }
     if(st.size()%2==1){
        q.add(st.pop());
       
     }
  
    for(int k = 0; k<size; k++){
     
        st.push(q.remove());
                st.push(q.remove());
       
    }
    
}
```

NEW VERSION

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();   
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
        a = st.pop();
        b = st.pop();
        st.push(a);
    }
    q.add(b);
    q.add(a);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }
}
```

Third attempt (infinite loop)

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();   
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
      a = st.pop();
        if(st.isEmpty()){
            st.push(a);
        }
    }
    b = st.pop();
    q.add(a);
    q.add(b);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }
}
```

Fourth Attempt: Works only on even number of elements..

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();   
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(st.size() > 1){
      a = st.pop();


    b = st.pop();
    q.add(b);
    q.add(a);
    }

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }

    while(!st.isEmpty()){
        q.add(st.pop());
    }
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }



}
```

FIFTH FINAL ATTEMPT:

I just need to find out what to do with an odd stack:

This works with even numbers of stacks;

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();   
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
      a = st.pop();
        if(st.isEmpty()){
            q.add(a);
        } 

        else {
    b = st.pop();
    q.add(b);
    q.add(a);
        }

        }

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }
    
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
        q.add(st.pop());
    }
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        st.push(q.remove());
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Clearly what you want to do??? switch meaning shifting??

Comment: Do you want to swap _pairs_ of elements, as in `1,2,3,4,5,6 -> 2,1,4,3,6,5` ?

Comment: just edited to be more clear, yes pax

Comment: why are you doing `st.clear()` for every iteration in the foor loop?

Comment: Shouldn't you just loop over every two elements? Like using `i += 2` as increment instead of `i++`?

Comment: oops, got rid of that.  Here is the original problem...I've been stuck for 3 days...http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=University+of+Washington+CSE+143/CS2+Exams/CS2+Midterm+Exams/143+Practice+Midterm+12&problem=143practicemidterm12-switchPairs

Comment: In your third attempt, the `b = pop, q.add a, q.add b` should be inside the loop, not after it, and you should be adding `b,a` in that order, not `a,b`. I've tried to make the control structures more obvious in my answer (with `endif` and `endwhile`), hopefully that will help.

Comment: inside the while or if?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A basic void method for switching pairs of integers in a stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029147/a-basic-void-method-for-switching-pairs-of-integers-in-a-stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap pairs of elements, here's what you need (in pseudo-code):

```
# Transfer to a queue, swapping pairs

create empty queue

while stack not empty:
    a = stack.pop
    if stack empty:
        queue.add a
    else
        b = stack.pop
        queue.add b
        queue.add a
    endif
endwhile

# Transfer back to stack (in reverse order, unfortunately)

while queue not empty:
    stack.push queue.get
endwhile

# Re-reverse the order to fix it up

while stack not empty:
    queue.add stack.pop
endwhile
while queue not empty:
    stack.push queue.get
endwhile
```

The way this works is to pop *two* elements at a time, swap them and add them to the queue, up until the stack is empty. Special handling is needed when you don't have a pair left. In that case, you just transfer the single element to the queue.

The processing of the queue is fairly simple as the pairs have already been swapped. You simply extract them from the queue and push them back on to the stack.

Unfortunately, the stack/queue combo has now put the items on the stack in the reverse order, so you need to do *another* transfer (but without swapping this time) to get them back to the correct order.

---

Now keep in mind that solution leaves the *earliest-pushed* element alone if it's the odd one out. In other words, the transformation is (`7` was pushed first):

```
7     7
6     5
5     6
4 --> 3
3     4
2     1
1     2
```

If you want the *last-pushed* to be excluded from the swapping, as in:

```
7     6
6     7
5     4
4 --> 5
3     2
2     3
1     1
```

you simply reverse the order in the stack *before* doing the swapping rather than after:

```
# Reverse the order up-front

create empty queue

while stack not empty:
    queue.add stack.pop
endwhile
while queue not empty:
    stack.push queue.get
endwhile

# Transfer to a queue, swapping pairs

while stack not empty:
    a = stack.pop
    if stack empty:
        queue.add a
    else
        b = stack.pop
        queue.add b
        queue.add a
    endif
endwhile

# Transfer back to stack, fixing up reversal in the process

while queue not empty:
    stack.push queue.get
endwhile
```

That subtle change won't affect the even-sized queues but it will ensure the stand-alone item in odd-sized queues is at the other end.

Comment: I got a empty stack exception...see new version

Comment: That might be right, but - and this is the tricky thing - OP is not allowed to use any additional auxiliary variables/data structures (only one stack and queue). So `a` and `b` are not allowed.

Comment: Tried again and got an infinite loop?

Comment: @exception1. from the link given: You may not use any other auxiliary data structures to solve this problem, although you can have as many simple variables as you like.

Comment: @user3349062, then you haven't implemented the pseudo-code correctly. Your `b=pop;q.add(b);q.add(a)` should be _inside_ the `while` loop. I'll make the pseudo-code more explicit. And you need to add `b` and `a` _in that order._

Comment: I first thought 'simple varibles' means `int` etc. but if references are also allowed (which now makes more sense if I rethink) you are right.

Comment: @paxdiablo my fourth attempt is perfect but only for even number of elements...?

Comment: @user3349062, actually, you're right, and I see you've already put in the code to get around my original bug of leaving the stack reversed (I've also amended this answer to fix that). With that fix in, you can't just put the last single element back on the stack, you need to transfer it to the queue along with the others, otherwise it'll be in the wrong place. See my updated pseudo-code, specificlly the first `queue.add a` inside my first `while` loop.

Comment: @paxdiablo i'm just having trouble figuring out how to maneuver around an extra integer...

Comment: @user3349062, that fifth attempt works fine for odd stack size (as well as even), It turns `7654321` (where `1` is the last element pushed) into `7563412` as desired.

Comment: @paxdiablo but how can i leave the odd number untouched? So it would be 6745231

Comment: @paxdiablo as in.. the number on the farthest right or "top" of stack

Comment: @user3349062, I think I understand now, you want the odd-man-out to be at the _other_ end of the stack. That's a simple re-arrangement of the code so that you reverse the order first before doing the swapping. See the update.